# Why ReferenceEquals and == operator behave different from Equals

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, proxy

I have an Entity that doesn't override any of the equality members\operators.
When comparing two proxies of them (I got them from the `Nhibernate session`) the result changes according to the equality method:

- ReferenceEquals(first, second) - false.
- first == second - false
- Equals(first, second) - true.

This is even more weird as they both exist in the same session context and according to the [Nhibernate docs](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode):

> NHibernate only guarantees identity ( a == b , the default
>   implementation of Equals()) inside a single ISession!`

And:

> The instance is currently associated with a persistence context. It
>   has a persistent identity (primary key value) and, perhaps, a
>   corresponding row in the database. For a particular persistence
>   context, NHibernate guarantees that persistent identity is equivalent
>   to CLR identity (in-memory location of the object).

So why not all of the equality methods return true?

---

**Update:**
I get the enteties this way, Query the session for ChildEntity and get the Parents Entities with Linq's `select`, similar to this:

```
var childs = session.Query<Child>();
var parents = childs.Select(x => x.ParentEntity).ToList();
```

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title - your sample shows == and ReferenceEquals behaving the same way.

Comment: My guess would be that two separate proxies are 'pointing' to the same instance, so that the proxies do not fulfill reference equality, but the Equals method gets marshalled, so that they are reported as equal.

Comment: How do you obtain the both objects from the session? In my experience the == equality works reliably. So my guess would be that either Nhibernate thinks both entities actually represent different database rows or they belong to different sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I get `childs` from the session I Merge them with the session.

```
var childs = session.Query<Child>();
// Do some stuff
foreach (var child in childs)
{
    session.Merge(child);
}

var parents = childs.Select(x => x.ParentEntity).ToList();
```

It appear that the merge detached the entity from the session and return a new Proxy attached to the session.

It can be fixed with

```
var newChild = (Child)session.Merge(child);
// Or:
session.Update(child); // (We have session.Clear() in our tests so I can't use this because it makes troubles when you update detached Entity
```

Comment: If you had mentioned you were using `Merge`, the conversation would have been much shorter :-)

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, So am I right? Does Merge detach the proxy from the session context? I asked it in the nhusers group: http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_frm/thread/7f5ec48858dd3904 and no one replied, And I can't find it in the Docs.

Comment: I have no idea what is in the `//Do some stuff` block (again, you are hiding possibly important details), but I don't understand what you are trying to use `Merge` for.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, You are right, My company doesn't allow me to write  the codes here... **:(** But there really nothing special, only queries and data changes. I'm using Merge because in the **testing** the Proxy is detach because before we call the method there is a session.Clear() so session.Update throws exception in this case... =( , do you have a better solution? (except delete the stupid session.Clear {I can't delete it, not my call...})

Comment: at this point, there's not much I can help you with. Your actual problem looks nothing like what you originally described, and is mostly caused by an incorrect of NHibernate. Using `session.Clear` breaks all the stated warranties about object identity.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

You might be using a struct? See below

---

I suppose reference types show the behaviour you expect:

```
public class Program    {
    class X { int x,y; }    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X a = new X();
        X b = new X();
        System.Console.WriteLine(a == b);
        System.Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
        System.Console.WriteLine(Equals(a,b));
        System.Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a,b));
} }
```

Prints:

```
False
False
False
False
```

For structs, things are different (commeting out the `a==b` test, which doesn't compile for structs:)

```
public class Program {
    struct X { int x,y; }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X a = new X();
        X b = new X();
        //System.Console.WriteLine(a == b);
        System.Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
        System.Console.WriteLine(Equals(a,b));
        System.Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a,b));
} }
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```

### Rationale:

The default implementation of Equals() comes from class `ValueType`, which is implicit base class of all value types. You may override this implementation by defining your own Equals() method in your struct. `ValueType.Equals()` always returns false when one compares objects of different (dynamic) types. If objects are of the same type, **it compares them by calling `Equals()` for each field**. If any of these returns false, the whole process is stopped, and final result is false. If all field-by-field comparisons return true, final result is true

Answer (score 0):

If `ReferenceEquals` returns false, you are clearly comparing two different instances.

Equals might still be true if it's overridden, but I don't think that's where the actual problem is.

I'd like to know how you're mapping and getting those objects, because as the docs say, **you can never get two different objects of the same type representing the same row in the same session.**

Comment: Updated my post. I don't think there is something interesting in the mapping. maybe in the query

Comment: OK, so you got a list of `parents`, some of which represent the same row (i.e. have the same POID), but are not the same object. Is that it?

Comment: Yes that is the story. I removed the Equals and GetHashCode as you suggested in the other post and look what happen... lol

Comment: Can you add your mappings and a sample comparison?

Comment: Not until next week... And what do you mean by _a sample comparison_

Comment: The piece of code where you are actually getting the two instances and comparing them. A failing unit test with no external dependencies, for example.

Comment: beside that the two entities should have the same reference, why the Equals return different value then == and ReferenceEquals when none of them were overridden?

Comment: I wrote what I found to be the problem and how I solved it. I would be glad to hear your opinion before I mark it as the accepted answer.