# Why does default == implementation not call Equals?

Tags: c#, java, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why ReferenceEquals and == operator behave different from Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344016/why-referenceequals-and-operator-behave-different-from-equals)

The default implementation of `==` operator compares objects by references. So when you override Equals (which default behaviour is the same) you have to also specify `==` and `!=` operators so that they call Equals (and make it in every class of hierarchy as `==` and `!=` operators are not virtual).

My question is why it is so? Why does `==` and `!=` compare objects by reference instead of using Equals? I guess there should be a reason for such a fundamental thing.

**Update.**

To comments: I assumed `==` should depend on Equals (but not vice versa) as you can override Equals in base class and use this implementation in derived classes automatically. It wouldn't work if Equals used `==` in its implementation, as `==` is not virtual.

Comment: By design, similar to Java, really.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, design decisions do not come from nowhere...

Comment: What should it do when both sides of the `==` are null?

Comment: Agreed, I'm just saying it's probably the same reasons that Java has == be reference equality and Equals() be overridable to provide equivalence.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, ok, so I will add Java tag to the question

Answer (score 10):

I believe the main reason is `==` is a **static** operator and can be called on `null` objects while `Equals` *requires an instance*.

For example:

```
Foo foo1 = null;
Foo foo2 = null;

Console.WriteLine(foo1 == foo2); // cannot use Equals
```

Comment: But Object.ReferenceEquals is also a static method

Answer (score 5):

Object.ReferenceEquals is a `static` member that compares *reference* equality. Even value types are boxed before being passed to that method.

What about `Equals`, it's a `virtual` method, which means it lets to a consumer to *override* a functionality.

So default implementation of `==` behavior presumes default comparison(reference) is ok for you, if you need something specific, in this case framework provides you with a `virtual` method, which *can* be overriden.

Comment: So default comparison (reference) is not ok for me and I override Equals but why have I to specify == and !=? What is the usecase when I override Equals but still need == and != to compare by reference?

Comment: @Idsa: if you want so, it's a true way to a mess :). There has to be *one* way of comparison in specified type(s). I think that is original idea of framework's designer. "Define me one way to compare this object, and it has to be single possible way, to avoid ambiguity".

Answer (score 2):

The "reason" is because sometimes one needs to know if A *is the same instance* as B as opposed to whether or not they are merely "equal" to each other.

For example, two objects being equal to each other may make sense for most of your business logic, however, you may also need to utilize some concurrency utilities which do atomic operations where the results are dependent on object identity, not equality.

Comment: But there is Object.ReferenceEquals for this case

Comment: Not in Java... which is also tagged for this question.

Comment: So the real question is why did the C# designers do this when they had all the benefit and knowledge of having seen Java in practice for a decade before designing the C# language. My guess would be consistency.

Comment: Unfortunately, C# used the same token for the reference-equality-test operator and overloadable-equality-test operator; a lot of code is written on the assumption that `foo == bar` will be equivalent to `Object.ReferenceEquals(foo, bar)`, but that assumption doesn't always hold.

Answer (score 1):

The == has been around and used for reference since C, and it's integrated into the language syntax rather than having to reply on method invocation (Even if results are the same for both).

Simply, because C# is not Objective C :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it is sometimes nice to quickly determine whether or not two identifiers are equal by simply comparing the references. `==` has it's place. If you look at an IDE generated `equals` method, you will often find that the first comparison made is reference equality, after all, why check the fields if the object references are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a feature.   By reference two identical objects are still two separate objects.  If you override Equals then you can determine if two objects are identical.  Even if two objects are identical I also might want to test if the are the same object.  I often have reason to override equals but never had the need to override ==  != (but that language provides that option).

With string they override == and I don't like it.   Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references (7.9.7 String equality operators). This makes testing for string equality more intuitive.   See the problem this introduced.   [WPF ListBox Scroll to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999859/wpf-listbox-scroll-to-the-bottom/10000879#10000879)